# Making a Web Dashboard with Discord and Oauth2 with Flask i need help to visualise it in html

Tags: python, flask

I want to make a web dashboard with discord oauth2 and flask
what i got:

```
@app.route("/login",methods = ["get"])
def login():
    code = request.args.get("code")
    access_token = Oauth.get_access_token(code)
    user_json = Oauth.get_user_json(access_token)
    username = user_json.get("username")
    user_hash = user_json.get("discriminator")
    user_avatar = user_json.get("avatar")
    user_id = user_json.get("id")
    
    return render_template('member_db.html')
```

i want that on the html site is something like "username"  in a template

my html:

```
<head>
    <tite></tite>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        
      <div>
      <a>{{ username }} </a>
      </div>
        
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

That doesnt work.
I just want that you can have the username in the html

Answer (score 3):

Add your username as a `kwarg` to your `render_template` function call:

```py
return render_template('member_db.html', username=username)
```

Flask uses Jinja templates. Read more about it [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/templates/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the context to render_template.

Please, take a look.

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates

Comment: i dont understand it right, could you give me an example for my code?

Comment: I see @M Z already did it. Read both references to better use Jinja and Flask Templates.